# Is the plane curve $y^3=x^4+x^3$ an irreducible algebraic affine set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, plane-curves

I'm dealing with the plane curve $C=\{(x,y)\in k^2:y^3=x^4+x^3\}$. I want to know if this curve is irreducible, where $k$ is a commutative field.

I know this is equivalent to the ideal $\sqrt{I}$ being prime, where $I=(Y^3-X^4-X^3)\subset k[X,Y]$, but so far I can't tell if $C$ is irreducible or if $I$ is prime.

I'd be most glad if someone tells me if this is true and how to prove. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is $Y^3 - X^4 - X^3$ irreducible in $k[X, Y]$ ? If so, then $I$ is a prime ideal of $k[X, Y]$ because $k[X, Y]$ is a UFD.

Comment: Note: A priori, this is equivalent to $\sqrt I$ being prime.

Comment: @JacksonHsu Is that retorical or you are asking like me? In case it is the first one, I know it is enough to prove that $Y^3-X^4-X^3$ is irreducible but I don't know it it is so.

Comment: @MooS Absolutely right, I'm editing it.

Comment: @Jonh I was just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Eisenstein to deduce that $y^3-x^3(x+1)$ is irreducible.

As an alternative, note that the polynomial (in the variable $y$) is primitive, of degree $3$ and has no roots. Then invoke the Gauß lemma.

Comment: I didn't know that Eisenstein's criterion could be used  in two variables. Where can I find this generalized version?

Comment: It is the usual version.

Comment: $p=x+1$ is a prime element of $k[x]$ and satisfies all assumptions of Eisenstein's criterion. Hence the polynomial is irreducible in $k(x)[y]$. It is primitive, hence by the Gauß lemma it is also irreducible in $k[x][y]$ and we are done.